# Man pages slow to open when booted from LAN

Tags: raspbian

I have my Raspberry PI 3B+ successfully booting Raspbian Stretch from LAN but it has an annoying issue in that man pages take approximately 15 seconds to load, ie. typing 'man bash' takes about 15 seconds before the page appears.  iperf results show that the connection is operating properly at about 300Mbit/s and the boot time is also comparable to booting from the SD card maybe even slightly faster it seems although I haven't timed it.  I haven't noticed anything else about the install that is slow.  What could be causing just the man pages to be slow?  Is there anything I could do to speed it up (apart from using an SD card)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man pages need to be compiled before they can be viewed. It browses the whole manual directory path and creates a lot of small temporary files each time you run man. If you do that through NFS, it will be substantially slower than just reading files over NFS.

You could use the `catman` utility to create a cache of precompiled manpages.